# How to get *any* example of boost::mpl::map working?

Tags: c++11, boost, metaprogramming

Here is my sample code. Can someone please help me with it?

```
#include <string>
#include <utility> //Not strictly necessary (gets imported implicitely anyway)
#include <boost/mpl/map.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/size.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>

typedef boost::mpl::map<
      std::pair<int,unsigned>
    , std::pair<char,unsigned char>
    > m;

int main()
{
    std::pair<int,unsigned> b(10,10); //this works
    int a = boost::mpl::size<m>::value; //this doesn't
}
```

The error message:

```
In file included from /home/adam/spack/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/boost-1.67.0-xcr4z3warx5tptvihmi5biqrq7hpgw7j/include/boost/mpl/map/aux_/include_preprocessed.hpp:47:0,
                 from /home/adam/spack/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/boost-1.67.0-xcr4z3warx5tptvihmi5biqrq7hpgw7j/include/boost/mpl/map/map10.hpp:28,
                 from /home/adam/spack/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/boost-1.67.0-xcr4z3warx5tptvihmi5biqrq7hpgw7j/include/boost/mpl/map/map20.hpp:19,
                 from /home/adam/spack/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/boost-1.67.0-xcr4z3warx5tptvihmi5biqrq7hpgw7j/include/boost/mpl/map.hpp:36,
                 from /home/adam/c++/tests/simple_test/test2.cpp:3:
/home/adam/spack/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/boost-1.67.0-xcr4z3warx5tptvihmi5biqrq7hpgw7j/include/boost/mpl/map/aux_/preprocessed/typeof_based/map10.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::mpl::map2<std::pair<int, unsigned int>, std::pair<char, unsigned char> >’:
/home/adam/spack/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/boost-1.67.0-xcr4z3warx5tptvihmi5biqrq7hpgw7j/include/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/map.hpp:51:8:   required from ‘struct boost::mpl::map<std::pair<int, unsigned int>, std::pair<char, unsigned char> >’
/home/adam/spack/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/boost-1.67.0-xcr4z3warx5tptvihmi5biqrq7hpgw7j/include/boost/mpl/aux_/has_tag.hpp:20:1:   required by substitution of ‘template<class U> static char (& boost::mpl::aux::has_tag<boost::mpl::map<std::pair<int, unsigned int>, std::pair<char, unsigned char> >, mpl_::bool_<false> >::gcc_3_2_wknd::test<U>(const volatile boost::mpl::aux::type_wrapper<T>*, boost::mpl::aux::type_wrapper<typename U::tag>*))[2] [with U = boost::mpl::map<std::pair<int, unsigned int>, std::pair<char, unsigned char> >]’
/home/adam/spack/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/boost-1.67.0-xcr4z3warx5tptvihmi5biqrq7hpgw7j/include/boost/mpl/aux_/has_tag.hpp:20:1:   required from ‘const bool boost::mpl::aux::has_tag<boost::mpl::map<std::pair<int, unsigned int>, std::pair<char, unsigned char> >, mpl_::bool_<false> >::value’
/home/adam/spack/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/boost-1.67.0-xcr4z3warx5tptvihmi5biqrq7hpgw7j/include/boost/mpl/aux_/has_tag.hpp:20:1:   required from ‘struct boost::mpl::aux::has_tag<boost::mpl::map<std::pair<int, unsigned int>, std::pair<char, unsigned char> >, mpl_::bool_<false> >’
/home/adam/spack/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/boost-1.67.0-xcr4z3warx5tptvihmi5biqrq7hpgw7j/include/boost/mpl/sequence_tag.hpp:110:8:   required from ‘struct boost::mpl::sequence_tag<boost::mpl::map<std::pair<int, unsigned int>, std::pair<char, unsigned char> > >’
/home/adam/spack/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/boost-1.67.0-xcr4z3warx5tptvihmi5biqrq7hpgw7j/include/boost/mpl/size.hpp:29:8:   required from ‘struct boost::mpl::size<boost::mpl::map<std::pair<int, unsigned int>, std::pair<char, unsigned char> > >’
/home/adam/c++/tests/simple_test/test2.cpp:15:29:   required from here
/home/adam/spack/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/boost-1.67.0-xcr4z3warx5tptvihmi5biqrq7hpgw7j/include/boost/mpl/map/aux_/preprocessed/typeof_based/map10.hpp:31:8: error: no type named ‘first’ in ‘struct std::pair<char, unsigned char>’
 struct map2
        ^~~~
In file included from /home/adam/c++/tests/simple_test/test2.cpp:4:0:
/home/adam/spack/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/boost-1.67.0-xcr4z3warx5tptvihmi5biqrq7hpgw7j/include/boost/mpl/size.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::mpl::size<boost::mpl::map<std::pair<int, unsigned int>, std::pair<char, unsigned char> > >’:
/home/adam/c++/tests/simple_test/test2.cpp:15:29:   required from here
/home/adam/spack/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/boost-1.67.0-xcr4z3warx5tptvihmi5biqrq7hpgw7j/include/boost/mpl/size.hpp:29:8: error: no class template named ‘apply’ in ‘struct boost::mpl::size_impl<boost::mpl::non_sequence_tag>’
 struct size
        ^~~~
/home/adam/c++/tests/simple_test/test2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/adam/c++/tests/simple_test/test2.cpp:15:31: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘boost::mpl::size<boost::mpl::map<std::pair<int, unsigned int>, std::pair<char, unsigned char> > >’
  int a = boost::mpl::size<m>::value; //this doesn't
                               ^~~~~
/home/adam/c++/tests/simple_test/test2.cpp:15:6: warning: unused variable ‘a’ [-Wunused-variable]
  int a = boost::mpl::size<m>::value; //this doesn't
      ^
CMakeFiles/libsimple_test.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/libsimple_test.dir/test2.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/libsimple_test.dir/test2.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:142: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/libsimple_test.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/libsimple_test.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I use C++11 on GCC 7.3.0 and libboost 1.67.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. Here it goes. @bolov

Answer (score 1):

By chance I found a solution: Don't use the standard `std::pair`, but rather use the re-invented `boost::mpl::pair`. After simple replacing `std::pair` into `boost::mpl::pair` the sample code compiles and runs properly... which leads to another question.

Comment: It is not "re-invented", it is a completely different thing for a completely different purpose. `boost::mpl::pair<A,B>` does ***not*** store elements of type `A` and `B`, unlike `std::pair`. `boost::mpl::pair<A,B>::first` and `boost::mpl::pair<A,B>::second` are *types*, while `std::pair<A,B>::first` and `std::pair<A,B>::second` are *values*. No surprise it didn't compile.

Comment: @lisyarus Doesn't being a value mean it also has to be of the proper type? What is wrong in using `std::pair` only for the types of the `::first` and `::second` (discarding the runtime values).

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski In the case of the MPL, the types `first` and `second` _are_ the values that the pair holds. For the standard pair, the runtime data that `first` and `second` have are the values, and those values _have_ types.