# What is the reason why boost::mpl doesn't use (and is even not compatible with) std::pair?

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, std

After spending many hours on a simple problem [How to get *any* example of boost::mpl::map working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51222558/1261153) regarding `boost::mpl::map` I fail to understand why boost doesn't embrace `std::pair` in their implementation of MPL. I understand, that they might miss bits and pieces in the standard pair, but surely they could include a code that adapts to the `std::pair`.

After all, `std::pair` is part of the language.

This phenomenon is not limited to `std::pair`. As I understand,  `std::tuple` is very much similar to the `boost::mpl::vector`, yet both types never interoperate in the boost library.

As @lisyarus on [How to get *any* example of boost::mpl::map working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51222558/1261153) pointed out, the difference is that in contrast to the `std::` version, `boost::mpl::pair` was never meant to store a value. But I still don't understand it - doesn't storing a value also mean that it has to keep the proper type? If all I care about are types, I can still use `std::pair` and its `::first` and `::second` members and simply discard the runtime value.

Comment: "Question number 2: Is there any hope, that Boost would eventually use standard containers in their MPL?" - you will have to ask the Boost people about that. Why don't you? They can answer, we can't.

Comment: @PasserBy you are right. Question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but surely they could include a code that adapts to the std::pair

One often-used variation is using EBO (Empty Baseclass Optimization) to reduce the size. You cannot "adapt" the standard library pair to do the same.

> As @lisyarus on How to get *any* example of boost::mpl::map working? pointed out, the difference is that in contrast to the std:: version, boost::mpl::pair was never meant to store a value.

Spot on. MPL = Meta Programming Library. Meta programming deals with compile-time "values" - which are to be encoded in types¹

> But I still don't understand it - doesn't storing a value also mean that it has to keep the proper type?

Yes of course. However, that's not what Boost MPL was designed for.

If you're looking for the library to *bridge* pure type-manipulation **and** runtime-values, you're in luck: that library is called Boost Fusion. And, unsurprisingly, Boost Fusion **does** adapt `std::pair` as a Fusion Sequence if  you include

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
```

> If all I care about are types, I can still use std::pair and its ::first and ::second members and simply discard the runtime value.

Yes you can. But you don't need Boost MPL then. Again, to bridge it, consider using Boost Fusion.

> **Note** Even more modern would be to use [Boost Hana](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html), which is like Boost Fusion and MPL combined **but** with C++11/14 style:
>
> > Hana is a header-only library for C++ metaprogramming suited for
> >     computations on both types and values. The functionality it provides
> >     is a superset of what is provided by the well established Boost.MPL
> >     and Boost.Fusion libraries. By leveraging C++11/14 implementation
> >     techniques and idioms, Hana boasts faster compilation times and
> >     runtime performance on par or better than previous metaprogramming
> >     libraries, while noticeably increasing the level of expressiveness in
> >     the process. Hana is easy to extend in a ad-hoc manner and it provides
> >     out-of-the-box inter-operation with Boost.Fusion, Boost.MPL and the
> >     standard library.

---

¹ well, until `constexpr` evaluation, but that came MUCH later than Boost MPL was written/designed